# Android 13 "Intent does not match component`s intent filter" trying to Share video via TikTok SDK

Tags: android, react-native, tiktok

Please help. We connected TikTok SDK to our react-native App (react-native-tiktok package). Auth function works well but not Share.

`Intent does not match component's intent filter: Intent { flg=0x8000 cmp=com.zhiliaoapp.musically/com.ss.android.ugc.aweme.share.SystemShareActivity (has extras) } Access blocked: ComponentInfo{com.zhiliaoapp.musically/com.ss.android.ugc.aweme.share.SystemShareActivity`

We tried to manage intent-filters and other options in AndroidManifests of our project and react-native-tiktok, but no changes in error.

Expecting result - after calling "share" function (NativeModules.Tiktok.share) - TikTok app will open with passed video prepared for share

```
import { share } from 'react-native-tiktok';

export const shareTikTok = async (videoUrl, imageUrl, accessToken, cb) => {
   const cache = await RNFetchBlob.config({
     fileCache: true,
     appendExt: !videoUrl ? 'png' : 'mp4',
   }).fetch('GET', !videoUrl ? imageUrl : `https://${videoUrl}`);
    share(`${cache.path()}`, resp => {
     cb(resp);
}
```